# Chrome on Android keypress event reporting funny

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

I'm having a problem with Chrome on Android (86.0.4240.99) with an input box. Basically, I'm listening to the keydown event and manipulating the textbox so it feels more like a calculator entry / applies input masks as they type with commas, etc.

For the input I have:

```
type="text"
pattern="[0-9]*"
inputmode="decimal"
```

On the keydown event when you press the '.', the event object is whacky, with a key of 'Unidentified' and a keyCode of 229 (the comma does the exact same thing). The numbers seem to work fine, it's just the ',', '.', and the '-' buttons on the keyboard that come up that do this. With how I'm manually manipulating the input, I need to know when the decimal key is clicked but I can't distinguish.

Here's the KeboardEvent object:

```
{ altKey: false
bubbles: true
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: true
charCode: 0
code: ""
composed: true
ctrlKey: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: true
detail: 0
eventPhase: 0
isComposing: false
isTrusted: true
key: "Unidentified"
keyCode: 229
location: 0
metaKey: false
path: (22) [input#input-518, div.v-text-field__slot, div.v-input__slot, div.v-input__control, div.v-input.v-input--is-label-active.v-input--is-dirty.v-input--is-focused.theme--light.v-text-fiel…, div.col, div.row, div, div.container, div.v-window-item.v-window-item--active, div.v-window__container, div.v-window.v-item-group.theme--light.v-tabs-items, div.v-tabs.v-tabs--grow.theme--light, div.v-card__text, div#tasks.v-card.v-sheet.theme--light, div.v-dialog.v-dialog--active.v-dialog--persistent, div.v-dialog__content.v-dialog__content--active, div#app.v-application.v-application--is-ltr.theme--light, body, html.overflow-y-hidden, document, Window]
repeat: false
returnValue: false
shiftKey: false
sourceCapabilities: InputDeviceCapabilities {firesTouchEvents: false}
srcElement: input#input-518
target: input#input-518
timeStamp: 489740.7000000003
type: "keydown"
view: Window {window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}
which: 229
}
```

Has anyone run into this or know how to fix it? Is it a bug in chrome for android? It works perfectly on Chrome for windows as well as on iOS.